# Filter data from Firestore whit angularfire

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to filter data from Firestore with Angularfire's Querying Collection: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md I'm a bit confused with the approach. I have managed to filter through a button but I do not know how to reset or remove that filter once done.

What is the correct way to filter and reset said filter?

Here I have a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/query-collections-in-angularfire2

My code so far:

**service.ts**

```
filterBy() {
  this.avisos = this.afs.collection('avisos', ref => ref.where('categoria','==', 'Vehículos' )).valueChanges()
  return this.avisos;
};
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
filtrarData() {
  this.avisos = this.fs.filterBy()
  return this.avisos;
};
```

**myComponent.html**

```
<button (click)="filtrarData()" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Vehículos</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your firebase service, there are two methods, one to get the collection with no filters and one to get the collection filtered by a given 'categoria'.

In your component, when gets initialized (`ngOnInit()` function) you call the method from the service to retrieve the whole collection; and then the button 'Vehiculos' triggers the function `filtrarData()` with the given 'categoria' from your service.

After it has been filtered, if you want to "clean" the filter and get the whole collection back, it would be as easy as having a button calling the same as `ngOnInit()` is doing and then your array `this.avisos` would have again the whole collection:

**app.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAvisos()
  }

  getAvisos() {
      this.avisos = this.fs.getDomiciliarios()
  }

  filtrarData() {
      this.avisos = this.fs.filterBy()
  }
```

then in the html of the component **app.component.html**:

```
<button (click)="getAvisos()" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mx-1">Clean Filters</button>
<span>Filter by:</span>
<button (click)="filtrarData()" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mx-1">Vehículos</button>
<hr>
```

By the way, notice that there is no need to do the `return this.avisos` line in the app.component.ts, that would only be needed for the service.

Additionally, would be good if you standardise a bit the firebase.service function to get the collection filtered by 'categoria' with an argument, in case you want to call it for more than one type of 'categoria':

**firebase.service.ts**

```
filterBy(categoriaToFilter: string) {
    this.avisos = this.afs.collection('avisos', ref => ref.where('categoria','==', categoriaToFilter )).valueChanges()

    return this.avisos;
};
```

so now in your **app.component.html** you could have something like:

```
<button (click)="filtrarData('Vehículos')" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mx-1">Vehículos</button>

<button (click)="filtrarData('Casa')" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mx-1">Casa</button>
```

but take into account that your component **app.component.ts** would then include:

```
filtrarData(categoriaToFilter: string) {
    this.avisos = this.fs.filterBy(categoriaToFilter)
}
```

Comment: This was perfect! it worked for me I was just thinking how to do it with several filters and you read my mind. Thank you very much. I am trying to use ngFor for many buttons. So I'm trying something like this: `<button * ngFor = "let categoria of categorias" (click) = "filtrarData ('categoria.nombre')" class = "btn btn-light border btn-sm mx-1"> {{ categoria.nombre}} </ button>` but it does not work for me, I will continue investigating. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: your error is in the evaluation inside filtrarData(), you are passing categoria.nombre as a string, when in reality you want to evaluate the variable, so remove the single quotes:

<button *ngFor = "let categoria of categorias" (click) = "filtrarData (categoria.nombre)" class = "btn btn-light border btn-sm mx-1"> {{ categoria.nombre}} </ button>